# first div in jquery-ui accordion must be open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

Attempting to use the nested jquery ui accordion here:

http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/VYbSU/4/

But I need the first div to be open as the default. Here is the code from fiddle:

```
$("div.accordian").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: false,


  });
```

There was some other code from another fiddle (but I forget where) using the following code:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({

   header: "> h3:not(.item)",
   heightStyle:"content",
   active:true,
   collapsible:true
```

});

but in that code, all the divs are initially closed as well.

Thanks in advance for your help!

regards, umbre gachoong

Answer (score 0):

Check the JSFIddle :- [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VYbSU/497/)

Remove the code :-

```
 active: false,
```

Answer (score 0):

there is some mistake in your code, i suggest you to use following code.

```
$("div.accordian").accordion({
    autoHeight: false,
    collapsible: true,
    active: 0
});
```